# Convergence of Definite Improper Integrals of the Form $1/x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Given a simple integral of the form: $$ \int ^1 _{-1} \frac{1}{x} \, dx =\lim _{a\rightarrow 0} \int ^1 _a \frac{1}{x} \, dx + \int ^a _{-1} \frac{1}{x} \, dx$$

Is it possible to say that this integral converges? I was told explicitly by my professor that this sort of improper definite integral can be said to converge in the sense of "Cauchy" but I can't find anything to back up his claim. I had posted another question about this where I was told if you can't assign a finite value to one of these integrals, it can't be said to exist. So for this simple example, we have $$\lim _{a\rightarrow 0} \int ^1 _a \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \lim _{a \rightarrow 0} [\ln (1)- \ln(a)] = -\infty$$

So you end up with $\infty - \infty$ for the entire interval which is undefined.  He never clarified what he really meant by "Cauchy", so I'm left to guess he means the [integral test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence), which doesn't seem to apply here since we're asking wethere this definite integral is defined in the first place.

Comment: Look up "Cauchy principal value", I think that's what he means.  [Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyPrincipalValue.html) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int_{-1}^{-a} \frac{dx} x + \int_a^1 \frac{dx}x = 0 \to 0.
$$

However:
\begin{align}
& \int_{-1}^{-2a} \frac{dx} x + \int_a^1 \frac{dx}x = \Big(\log|{-2a}| - \log |{-1}|\Big) + \Big( \log 1 - \log a \Big) \\[10pt]
= {} & \log(2a) - \log a = \log \frac{2a} a = \log 2 \approx 0.693\ldots 
\end{align}

As $a\downarrow 0$, the sets $(-1,-a)\cup(a,1)$ and $(-1,-2a)\cup(a,1)$ both approach $(-1,1)$, but the way in which the bounds approach $0$ alters the value of the integral.  The first one is singled out as the "principal value", in a sense that the conventional language attributes to Cauchy.  What the actual history is, and hence how much credit or blame for this Cauchy deserves, is a different question.

(A bit more precisely: $\displaystyle\bigcup_{a>0} (-1,-a)\cup(a,1)$ and $\displaystyle\bigcup_{a>0} (-1,-a)\cup(a,1)$ are both equal to $(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$, which includes all of $[1,1]$ except a set whose measure is $0$.)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the original integral doesn't exist, but if you take the limit of it, it does? It seems to me to be a bit like saying though $f(0) = \sin (0)/0 = 1$. If you don't specify the limit, it doesn't make sense, correct?

Comment: @Astrum : Yes. ${}\qquad{}$